# Use FE estimates for OLS

Tags: r, statistics

I am analyzing a panel data set and I am interested in some time-independent explanatory variables(z). The Hausmann Test shows that I should use a fixed effects model instead of a random effects model.

Downside is, that the model will not estimate any coefficients for the time-independent explanatory variables.

So one idea is to take the estimated coefficients(b) for the time-dependent variables(x) from the FE model and use them on the raw data which means, take out the effects from the already estimated explanatory variables. Then use this corrected values as dependent variable for an OLS model with the time-independent variables as explanatory variables. This leads to:

```
y - x'b = z'j + u (with j as coefficients of interesst)
```

Do these two models exclude each other with any necessary assumption or is it just that the standard errors of the OLS model need to be corrected?

Thanks for every hint!

Comment: First of all, this questions should be on Cross Validated. However, if I might give my two cents, your idea is unnecessarily complicated. Simply estimate a random effects model and, for the time-variant predictors, include a group mean in addition to the original variable. The original variable then reproduces fixed effects estimates while the group-mean variable gives you an idea about cross-sectional variation. I can provide ample literature if you need it

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hint. Additional and more detailed literature would be very nice.

Comment: [Mundlak 1978](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Econometrics/Mundlak-1978.pdf);  [Bell & Jones 2005](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-science-research-and-methods/article/explaining-fixed-effects-random-effects-modeling-of-timeseries-crosssectional-and-panel-data/0334A27557D15848549120FE8ECD8D63); [Allison 2009](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiw5qylwInYAhVFyKQKHfbwAlAQFggrMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fus.sagepub.com%2Fen-us%2Fnam%2Ffixed-effects-regression-models%2Fbook226025&usg=AOvVaw042btBcWVfFokxu3oUBNS9)

Comment: Also [Bafumi & Gelman 2006](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/Bafumi_Gelman_Midwest06.pdf)